# Oracle REGEXP search a pattern and do operation before replacement

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I have data in Oracle 11g and have 2 scenarios to solve, can someone here suggest a solution

> **sample data in column**: **Name1**-Value1+**Name2**-Value2+**Name3**-Value3a+ Value3b+**Name4**-
>   Value4a+Value4b + Value4c+**Name5**-Value5+

Note that '+' is a delimiter between *names* and also between *sub-values* (like in case of Value3a and value3b)

There are 2 problems to solve

1. Find sub-string(s) where + is a sub-value delimiter and replace it with space. 
   I tried but it doesn't work when there are more than one value separator as in this case Value4a+Value4b + Value4c)

   `REGEXP_REPLACE(column_value, '\+([^-]*\+)[^$]', \1)`

> Two + without a - in between tells me that they are sub-value
>   separator and that's what I am using here in pattern.

I have a 2-step approach to solve this problem but I am trying to see if a single statement (nested is fine) can solve it (in case something like below is doable)

`REGEXP_REPLACE(column_value, '\+([^-]*\+)[^$]', Replace all + with space from \1)`

2. Second is, is there a way that I can define 2 or more patterns to search

`REGEXP_REPLACE(column_value, Pattern one or pattern2, replacement_string)`

Thank you for reading the question

Comment: can you provide sample output for your example for your two cases

Comment: also + is a regular expression keyword so you need to escape it with \+

Comment: Thanks psaraj. I corrected the SQL in question, actually this is a made up example based on a real situation we are facing (in that we don't use + so I missed to note that it wasn't escaped here).

Comment: can you provide the sample output for made up example just to be clear

Comment: you can use REGEXP_SUBSTR for checking what pattern is currently matching SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (column_value,'\+([^-]*\+)[^$]',level ) FROM YOUR_TABLE 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT 
(column_value, '\+([^-]*\+)[^$]');

Comment: Since Oracle regex is not that powerful, you can only use your 2 step approach.